# Why new line escape character doesn't work in my case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the line that doesn't work:

```
const modalContent = () => `First line.\nSecond line?`;
```

I use it in React app in my component.

Comment: Please don't use "doesn't work". It's not informative. Explain what does vs. what you expect.

Comment: Please explain exactly what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: The whole string is in one line, not in two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In normal HTML the line-break is simply handled like a normal space. There are two solutions.

1. You tell the surrounding html element with css that line-breaks and whitespaces are important. This is done f.e. by setting the style `white-space` to `pre`.
2. You set the return-value of your function not to a string but to a jsx. Then you can use a `br` element for a line-break:

`const modalContent = () => <span>First line.<br/>Second line?</span>;`

Answer (score 0):

The new line is created in the string:

```js
const modalContent = () => `First line.\nSecond line?`
console.log(modalContent());
```

… but a new line in HTML is treated just like any other kind of white space.

```html
First line.
Second line?
```

You need a `<br>` element instead of a new line, or CSS which sets `white-space` to a value where new lines are significant (such as `pre`).

```html
First line.<br>
Second line?
```

Comment: I've already tried with <br>. It prints: First line.<br>Second line?

Comment: @tesicg you need a br _element_, not a string `<br>`. You can use JSX to get one.

Comment: @Tom Fenech: I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are using the backtick. This resembles a template string in ES6. It will respect any empty lines in the actual string. \n Will work in a regular string with single or double quotes

So:

```js
const multi = `
this is
multiline
text
`;

const text = "this is not \nmultiline\ntext";

console.log(multi);
console.log(text)
```

Comment: It doesn't work either with single or double quotes.